# Preventing divs from overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I need help sizing the `post-title` div correctly at the following link. If you scale the result panel so that it is narrower, eventually the title will overlap the date. Rather than overlapping as shown here:

[image: Overlapping example]

I would prefer that the title wrap onto a new line to avoid this collision. optimally, I would like it to also make use of the area above the the date like so:

[image]

Currently, the title will wrap once it reaches the end of the containing `post` div, as shown by the blue line beneath the title.

I have included a JSFiddle for you to test with.

http://jsfiddle.net/sph74/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float: right` on the date to get close to what you want.  No more `absolute` positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/sph74/1/

This is done via `float: right` (and that alone on the date).  The `.post-title` element has to be `display: inline` or `inline-block`  You could also use `float: left`, but that makes things a lot more hectic.

You also need to properly `clear` after the `.post-heading` element which I have done the old fashioned way via `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Makes sense to me! It ended up displaying beneath the line, but it turns out I like it better there anyway =p